# How to remove backslashes from json response in php

Tags: php, json

I am getting json response as mentioned below:

```
"{\"id\":\"order_DPUVoS2YVnBccy\",\"entity\":\"order\",\"amount\":100,\"amount_paid\":0,\"amount_due\":100,\"currency\":\"INR\",\"receipt\":\"7550\",\"offer_id\":null,\"status\":\"created\",\"attempts\":0,\"notes\":[],\"created_at\":1570082483}"
```

I want output to be as:

```
{"id":"order_DPUVoS2YVnBccy","entity":"order","amount":100,"amount_paid":0,"amount_due":100,"currency":"INR","receipt":"7550","offer_id":null,"status":"created","attempts":0,"notes":[],"created_at":1570082483}
```

I tried using `stripslashes()` to remove **backslashes**, but its not working.

Comment: please add some code you have tried to solve this problem

Comment: $data=stripslashes($jsondata);

echo json_encode($data);

$jsondata is the response from api call

Comment: https://www.tehplayground.com/c7BpE3Rf6VL8o6lF it worked :/

Comment: just echo this data

Comment: now when i pass $json into foreach() to fetch each data..its giving invalid foreach argument

Comment: may be regex can help if you can identify the pattern

Comment: You have to use `json_decode($json, true)` to turn the JSON into an array to pass it to foreach. `json_encode()` is used to convert array into a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "not working"?

```
<?php

$unescapedJson = '{\"id\":\"order_DPUVoS2YVnBccy\",\"entity\":\"order\",\"amount\":100,\"amount_paid\":0,\"amount_due\":100,\"currency\":\"INR\",\"receipt\":\"7550\",\"offer_id\":null,\"status\":\"created\",\"attempts\":0,\"notes\":[],\"created_at\":1570082483}';

echo stripslashes($unescapedJson);
```

[Output for PHP 7.1.25 - 7.4.0rc2](https://3v4l.org/T2Do9#v7125):

> {"id":"order_DPUVoS2YVnBccy","entity":"order","amount":100,"amount_paid":0,"amount_due":100,"currency":"INR","receipt":"7550","offer_id":null,"status":"created","attempts":0,"notes":[],"created_at":1570082483}

Comment: after stripping slash from the JSON, OP uses `json_encode()` on that string, which will put back the slashes: https://3v4l.org/iGfVV

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it when json decode:

```
$data = json_encode('yourjsonvariable'), true, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: I want output using php not javascript